# SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2 - Failed Cluster Node

Tags: sql-server-2005, cluster, service-pack

We have SQL server 2005 running on our cluster with Service Pack 2.

However one of the nodes failed, after rebuilding the node I added the node back to the clster with SQL server setup. However it gave me a warning that the version being installed (without service pack) was different the the version running (SP2).

I continued anyway assuming I could install the service pack after the node was added (as recommended in the warning message).

So now the node has been added I run the SP2 setup on the rebuilt node, however the installation will not update the MSSQLSERVER\Database Services part. It tels me it can only update on the active node.

How do I get this node into a state capable of fail over?

Many Thanks,
Ady

Answer (score 0):

Apply Service Pack 2 to the Active Node again and it will update both nodes of the cluster.